# Python Program with Ending Error

Tags: python, string

I am currently using this code

```
word = input('Enter a word: ')   
count = 0
vowels = ['a' , 'e' , 'i' ,'o' , 'u']
for char in word:
    if char in vowels: 
        count += 1
if count == 1:
  print(word + ' contains ' + str(count) + ' vowel') 
elif count > 1:
  print(word + ' contains ' + str(count) + ' vowels')
elif count < 1:
  print(word + ' contains ' + str(count) + ' vowels')  
elif word == "":
  print("")
```

it works fine up until the part when the input is an empty space. 
instead of not producing anything, and ending the program, it produces this instead

```
Enter a word: 
 contains 0 vowels
```

can anyone tell me what im doing wrong or help me out?

Comment: Why do you think that's wrong? `''` *does* contain no vowels (and you test `count < 1` before you test `word == ""`).

Comment: Because i don't want the program producing "contains no vowels" i want the program to not respond @jonrsharpe

Comment: Since one of `count < 1`, `count == 1` and `count > 1` must always be true, any elifs after that can never be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You test things in the wrong order: for the input `word == ''`, `count == 0` so the condition `count < 1` is `True` and `elif word == ""` is **never reached**. Instead, reorder the tests:

```
if not word: # more Pythonic equivalent to 'if word == "":'
    print("")
elif count == 1:
  print(word + ' contains ' + str(count) + ' vowel') 
elif count > 1:
  print(word + ' contains ' + str(count) + ' vowels')
elif count < 1:
  print(word + ' contains ' + str(count) + ' vowels')
```

Alternatively, skip the rest of the program for an empty input:

```
word = input('Enter a word: ')   
if word:
    count = 0
    vowels = set("aeiou") # this makes the program more efficient
    ...
```

Comment: how would i make the program continue to ask "Enter a Word" until no word was entered? @jonrsharpe

Comment: @kikiaraab a `while` loop? This isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

```
if count == 1:
  print(word + ' contains ' + str(count) + ' vowel') 
elif count > 1:
  print(word + ' contains ' + str(count) + ' vowels')
elif count < 1:
  print(word + ' contains ' + str(count) + ' vowels')  
elif word == "":
  print("")
```

you will never reach last `elif`. Count is always `<1`, `== 1` or `> 1` (if it is a number) so one of the `if`s will trigger and produce a `print`.